# SQLite Join with Partial Match

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am working with two tables in SQLite(3.3.3) where I want to join them using a partial match on the course name.  I am currently using the code:

```
Select * from [School]
    Left Join Teacher_File ON
    Course_Name like '%' || Course || '%';
```

I get about a 45% match from the two tables.  I am trying to figure out why a match will not occur when there are similar words in each table.  For example:

`AP Calculus AB - B` will not match with `AP Calculus AB (Semesters A and B)`.
`Human Geography A - Honors` will not match with `Human Geography/World Geography Introduction to Communications` and `Speech A` will not match with `Introduction to Communication and Speech`.

Comment: `like` does not match similar strings. `%string%` matches values which contain *exactly* that string. `AP Calculus AB (Semesters A and B)` does not contain the complete string `AP Calculus AB - B` so it will not match. Nor the other way around. You should instead be joining on course IDs, not their names.

Comment: See [SQL Like](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_like.asp) for more info.

Comment: Unfortunately, the two tables do not have similar course ID.  That being said, I do get a match on PA-Common Core Algebra I A-CR with Algebra I although the strings do not match.

Comment: `PA-Common Core Algebra I A-CR` contains the string `Algebra I` so `%Algebra I%` will match `PA-Common Core Algebra I A-CR`. If you don't have an explicit way to join the courses, probably the best thing to do is to take this opportunity to fix your schema and add them now. It will be the same amount of work. You're probably going to have to do some heuristics and manual data entry.

Comment: If that is the case, why won't I get a match on AP Calculus AB - B and AP Calculus AB (Semesters A and B)?  Both contain the string AP Calculus AB.  As for the schema, we deal with hundreds of customers and they all name their courses differently.

Comment: If the 2 strings are Course_Name = 'AP Calculus AB - B' and Course = 'AP Calculus AB' then you should get a match and I'm sure that you get a match. If you don't get a match then the 2 strings do not have the values that you say they have.

Comment: @Paul `AP Calculus AB (Semesters A and B)` does not contain ***exactly*** `AP Calculus AB - B`. It's missing the ```- B```. For example, `'Semesters A and B' like '%Semesters A%'` matches because `Semesters A and B` contains ***exactly*** `Semesters A`. However, `'Semesters A and B' like '%Semesters B%'` won't match. Nor will `'Semesters A and B' like '%Semesters A - B%'`. It has to be an exact substring.

Comment: @Paul "*We deal with hundreds of customers and they all name their courses differently*" Sorry, there's no simple solution to matching human entered course titles. `like` just looks for exact substrings. If you want `AP Calculus AB (Semesters A and B)` and `AP Calculus AB - B` to reliably both match as `AP Calculus AB` you can add a table of normalized courses and have each customer's course reference that. The references will have to be made with heuristics and manual data entry.

Comment: @Paul What might have more success is to make a table of normalized courses like `AP Calculus AB` and `Algebra I` and search for matches against those normalized names. And probably have a human in the loop to confirm the matches.